# Get array in perl from json_encode

Tags: perl

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
```

I make this in php which is then called from perl:

```
      $data = array("id"=> $id, "message" => $test); 
      echo json_encode($data);
```

And from print `$data = perl->decoded_content` script, it return :

```
  {"id": "1234****", "message":"hi"};
```

But I can't manage to get `id` and `message`. I tried `$data{'id'}` and `$data->{'id'}`, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

To decode the JSON, you'd use

```
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

my $data = decode_json($json);
```

This will produce a *reference* to a *hash*, so

```
$data->{id}
```

Comment: Hi @ikegami Thank you for the respond. But it still return: 

can't use string `("{"id": "1234****", "message":"hi"}")` as a HASH ref while "strict refs"

Comment: @AlKasih You probably need to decode the JSON string first

Comment: white this: `$data = perl->decoded_content` ?, or this is still not enough?